# Optimization of a C++ code (that uses UnorderedMap and Vector)

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, unordered-map

I am trying to optimize some part of a C++ code that is taking a long time (the following part of the code takes about 19 seconds for X amount of data, and I am trying to finish the whole process in less than 5 seconds for the same amount of data - based on some benchmarks that I have). I have a function "add" that I have written and copied the code here. I will try to explain as much as possible that I think is needed to understand the code. Please let me know if I have missed something.

The following function add is called X times for X amount of data entries.

```
void HashTable::add(PointObject vector)   // PointObject is a user-defined object
{
    int combinedHash = hash(vector);   // the function "hash" takes less than 1 second for X amount of data

   // hashTableMap is an unordered_map<int, std::vector<PointObject>>

   if (hashTableMap.count(combinedHash) == 0)
   {
        // if the hashmap does not contain the combinedHash key, then 
        //  add the key and a new vector
        std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList;
        pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
        hashTableMap.insert(std::make_pair(combinedHash, pointVectorList));
   }
   else
   {
        // otherwise find the key and the corresponding vector of PointObjects and add the current PointObject to the existing vector
        auto it = hashTableMap.find(combinedHash);
        if (it != hashTableMap.end())
        {
            std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList = it->second;
            pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
            it->second = pointVectorList;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is PointObject?  Is it a vector with 2, 3 or 4 values?  What type is it?  integer or real?  Is this a spatial hash?

Comment: I see you are transiting objects by value everywhere. Every time you do that, a copy operation happens. Pointers and performance are friends, use them.

Comment: PointObject has 2 attributes (int key and vector<float>)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are doing a lot of useless operations... if I understand correctly, a simplified form could be simply:

```
void HashTable::add(const PointObject& vector) {
   hashTableMap[hash(vector)].push_back(vector);    
}
```

This works because

- A map when accessed using `operator[]` will create a default-initialized value if it's not already present in the map
- The value (an `std::vector`) is returned by reference so you can directly `push_back` the incoming point to it. This `std::vector` will be either a newly inserted one or a previously existing one if the key was already in the map.

Note also that, depending on the size of `PointObject` and other factors, it could be possibly more efficient to pass `vector` by value instead of by `const PointObject&`. This is the kind of micro optimization that however requires profiling to be performed sensibly.

Comment: Thank you! The time for this function decreased from 19 seconds to 3 seconds! I am going to go over the rest of my code and make sure I am not doing something similar everywhere else. I changed my java code to C++ code for some comparison purposes, and did a line-by-line translation (my biggest mistake). Thanks again!

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to take the vector by value and `std::move()`ing it into the `hashTable`?

Comment: I thought Java was supposed to ease the life of previous C++ programmers. Turns out to be more painful?

Comment: @SiyuanRen this would be terrible code in any language, Java included.

Comment: @WorldSEnder: why would that make any significant difference?  What *could* help significantly - *if the caller doesn't need to keep their copy* - is an `add(PointObject&&* vector)` version, as that would avoid copying altogether....

Comment: @TonyD, if you take it by value `add(PointObject)` and move it into the vector, then the caller can either move his object = 2 moves, or he can copy his object = 1 move, 1 copy. Moves are pretty effecient and can be optimized away by the optimizer. The advantages: the caller decides to move or to copy and you don't have to code a superfluous overload.

Comment: @WorldSEnder: that reasoning is only valid if `PointObject` itself has a move constructor, whereas the "superfluous" overload works either way.  Of course, it's nice for `PointObject` to have such a constructor if it's useful....

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calling `hashTableMap.count(combinedHash)` and `hashTableMap.find(combinedHash)`, better just insert new element and check what [`insert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/) returned:

> In versions (1) and (2), the function returns a pair object whose
>   first element is an iterator pointing **either to the newly inserted
>   element in the container or to the element whose key is equivalent**,
>   and a bool value indicating whether the element was successfully
>   inserted or not.

Moreover, do not pass objects by value, where you don't have to. Better pass it by pointer or by reference. This:

```
std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList = it->second;
```

is inefficient since it will create an unnecessary copy of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Without the `if`, try to insert an empty entry on the hash table:

```
auto ret = hashTableMap.insert(
   std::make_pair(combinedHash, std::vector<PointObject>());
```

Either a new blank entry will be added, or the already present entry will be retrieved. In your case, you don't need to check which it the case, you just need to take the returned iterator and add the new element:

```
auto &pointVectorList = *ret.first;
pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
```

Answer (score 2):

This `.count()` is totally unecessary, you could simplify your function to:

```
void HashTable::add(PointObject vector)
{
    int combinedHash = hash(vector);
    auto it = hashTableMap.find(combinedHash);
    if (it != hashTableMap.end())
    {
        std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList = it->second;
        pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
        it->second = pointVectorList;
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList;
        pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
        hashTableMap.insert(std::make_pair(combinedHash, pointVectorList));
    }
}
```

You are also performing copy operations everywhere. Copying an object is time consuming, avoid doing that. Also use references and pointers when possible:

```
void HashTable::add(PointObject& vector)
{
    int combinedHash = hash(vector);
    auto it = hashTableMap.find(combinedHash);
    if (it != hashTableMap.end())
    {
        it->second.push_back(vector);
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList;
        pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
        hashTableMap.insert(std::make_pair(combinedHash, pointVectorList));
    }
}
```

This code can probably be optimized further, but it would require knowing `hash()`, knowing the way `hashTableMap` works (by the way, why is it not a `std::map`?) and some experimentation.

If `hashTableMap` was a `std::map<int, std::vector<pointVectorList>>`, you could simplify your function to this:

```
void HashTable::add(PointObject& vector)
{
    hashTableMap[hash(vector)].push_back(vector);
}
```

And if it was a `std::map<int, std::vector<pointVectorList*>>` (pointer) you can even avoid that last copy operation.

Answer (score 1):

Your **biggest** problem is that you're **copying the entire vector (and every element in that vector) twice** in the else part:

```
std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList = it->second;  // first copy
pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
it->second = pointVectorList;                           // second copy
```

This means that every time you're adding an element to an existing vector you're copying that entire vector.

If you used a reference to that vector you'd do a lot better:

```
std::vector<PointObject> &pointVectorList = it->second;
pointVectorList.push_back(vector);
//it->second = pointVectorList; // don't need this anymore.
```

---

On a side note, in your `unordered_map` you're hashing your value to be your key.
You could use an `unordered_set` with your hash function instead.

Comment: There is no need to use `std::shared_ptr`, he can just use the vector directly from the iterator, or take a reference for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::unordered_map` doesn't seem appropriate here - you use the `int` from `hash` as the key (which presumably) is the hash of `PointObject` rather than `PointObject` itself. Essentially double hashing. And also if you need a `PointObject` in order to compute the map key then it's not really a key at all! Perhaps `std::unordered_multiset` would be a better choice?

First define the hash function form `PointObject`

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<PointObject> {
        size_t operator()(const PointObject& p) const {
            return ::hash(p);
        }
    };
}
```

Then something like

```
#include <unordered_set>

using HashTable = std::unordered_multiset<PointObject>;

int main()
{
    HashTable table {};

    PointObject a {};
    table.insert(a);

    table.emplace(/* whatever */);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `PointObject` is big and making copies of it is expensive, `std::move` is your friend here. You'll want to ensure that `PointObject` is move-aware (either don't define a destructor or copy operator, or provide a move-constructor and move-assignment operator yourself).

```
void HashTable::add(PointObject vector)   // PointObject is a user-defined object
{
    int combinedHash = hash(vector);   // the function "hash" takes less than 1 second for X amount of data

   // hashTableMap is an unordered_map<int, std::vector<PointObject>>

   if (hashTableMap.count(combinedHash) == 0)
   {
        // if the hashmap does not contain the combinedHash key, then 
        //  add the key and a new vector
        std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList;
        pointVectorList.push_back(std::move(vector));
        hashTableMap.insert(std::make_pair(combinedHash, std::move(pointVectorList)));
   }
   else
   {
        // otherwise find the key and the corresponding vector of PointObjects and add the current PointObject to the existing vector
        auto it = hashTableMap.find(combinedHash);
        if (it != hashTableMap.end())
        {
            std::vector<PointObject> pointVectorList = it->second;
            pointVectorList.push_back(std::move(vector));
            it->second = std::move(pointVectorList);
        }
   }
}
```